# function arguments expected near ','

Tags: unit-testing, lua

I have a class defined like so:

```
local MyClass = {
 _VERSION = 'MyClass 1.0.0'
}
MyClass.__index = MyClass

setmetatable(MyClass, {
    __call = function (cls, ...)
        return cls.new(...)
    end
})

function MyClass.new(prop1)
    local self = setmetatable({}, MyClass)
    self.prop1 = prop1
    return self
end

function MyClass:msg(txt)
    self.prop1 = txt
    print(self.prop1)
end

function MyClass:callFunc(func, ...)
    pcall(func, ...)
end
```

My client code may look like:

```
local inst = MyClass("value 1")
inst:msg("Hello world")
inst:callFunc(inst:msg, "Hello again")
```

When I run this client code, I get an error message

> function arguments expected near ','

The code is completely reprodicible. You can easily check it [here](https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo). Just copy paste and run it and you will get this error message. How can I fix it?

Comment: What line does it point to?

Comment: It points to the last line where I call `callFunc`. By the way, I solved my problem myself. I will post a solution in a minute

Answer (score 9):

The problem is with using `inst:msg` in `inst:callFunc(inst:msg, "Hello again")`. The `:` syntax is only a "calling" convention (which is why it expects a function argument there), so can't be used to reference a method. You can simply replace it with `inst.msg` or `MyClass.msg` and get the same effect you expect without triggering the error.

Comment: I owe you so much time.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution. I got it just by chance. Here it is:

```
local MyClass = {
_VERSION = 'MyClass 1.0.0'
}
MyClass.__index = MyClass

setmetatable(MyClass, {
__call = function (cls, ...)
    return cls.new(...)
end
})

function MyClass.new(prop1)
    local self = setmetatable({}, MyClass)
    self.prop1 = prop1
    return self
end

function MyClass:msg(txt)
    if txt == nil then
        print(self.prop1)
    else
        self.prop1 = txt
        print("Two")
    end
end

function MyClass:callFunc(func, ...)
    pcall(func, ...)
end

-- client code

local inst = MyClass("value 1")
inst:callFunc(MyClass.msg, inst)
```

So, the main idea is to pass a function with dot notation as a first parameter and pass a class instance as a second parameter. Hope it will help someone.

Comment: it would help if you would explain what you actually want to achieve. then people could show you how to do it properly. that would be better than posting a problem and then an answer you found by accidcent. in your question you try to print "hello again" and in your answer you do something  completely different. I doubt this will help anyone

Comment: The whole problem was how to pass instance (not class) method to a function call. `instance:method` is not right, `instance.method` and `Class.method` are not completely right, because in this case you will not have access to instance properties. The secret sauce was to pass instance itself. I've never seen this in Lua tutorials.